# Why are different long values converted into the same date/time?

Tags: java, date, syntax, simpledateformat

```
public static void getTime() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Time t1 = new Time(Long.parseLong("1369213412435"));
    Time t2 = new Time(Long.parseLong("1369213412245"));
    System.out.println(sdf.format(t1));
    System.out.println(sdf.format(t2));
}
```

Why does the above code prints,

```
2013-05-22 17:03:32
2013-05-22 17:03:32
```

Comment: You put the format as `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. So you are getting like this. The input para that it takes is UTC time. A simple googling will provide much more u need.

Comment: why some have downvoted this question ?

Comment: This doesn't even compile. Where does your `Time` class come from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two dates differ only by milliseconds (435 or 245), which you ignore in your format.

Use:

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss SSS");
```

to see the different values.

Answer (score 4):

The only difference is in the milliseconds (435 vs 245).

Answer (score 4):

The two dates are differed by milliseconds i.e. `435` and `245`.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss SSS");
```

This will do.

Answer (score 3):

Use :

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS");
```

and you will see the difference in the milliseconds part.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the millisecond parts there are certain cases where two long values can provide same date.

i.e. below two long values have same millisecond and are different

- 1458065184000
- 1458021984000

If you use **dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss SSS** then it will give you the same result.

Catch here is hh (12 hr format) vs HH (24 hr format).

Using this will give the accurate result **dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss SSS**