# android Date and SimpleDateFormat output wrong

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

I do not know why different input but the output is duplicate, here is my code

```
        Date d = new Date(1409716800);
        Date d1 = new Date(1409716801);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy-HH:mm:ss");
        String formattedDate = sdf.format(d);
        String formattedDate1 = sdf.format(d1);         

        Log.d("time", formattedDate);
        Log.d("time", formattedDate1);
```

The output is

```
   10-24 06:12:50.508: D/time(29097): 17.01.70-07:35:16
   10-24 06:12:50.508: D/time(29097): 17.01.70-07:35:16
```

can anyone tell me why the output are duplicate? My timezone is GMT+7

Comment: Try printing seconds `"dd.MM.yy-HH:mm:ss" and you will see the difference.

Comment: my problem is duplicate in seconds...., updated code...

Comment: `1409716801` is in mili second so you wont get change in second give difference of 1000 mili seconds at least.

Comment: @jupiter dont put answer here.

Comment: Date constructor takes time in millis and not seconds..

Comment: thanks all, I knew my problem :). many thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are different long values converted into the same date/time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708785/why-are-different-long-values-converted-into-the-same-date-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Date d = new Date(1409716800);
    Date d1 = new Date(1409716801);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy-HH:mm:ss:SSS");
    String formattedDate = sdf.format(d);
    String formattedDate1 = sdf.format(d1);         

    Log.d("time", formattedDate);
    Log.d("time", formattedDate1);
```

Ouput:

```
    17.01.70-14:35:16:800
    17.01.70-14:35:16:801
```